# Chrome cast icon not showing on iOS devices having iOS 12 or above installed

Tags: xcode, chromecast, xcode10, ios12

The issue of chrome cast icon not showing up, occurs on devices having iOS 12 installed. 
Though on simulator the cast icon shows up.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to enable **"Access Wifi Information" in capabilities tab of your applications target settings in Xcode 10**.

Enabling this makes chrome cast devices discoverable by GCKCastContext's discovery manager. The cast icons shows up when any cast devices gets discovered.

[image]